# String concatenation with Null

Tags: java, string

I have the following code

```
System.out.println("" + null);
```

and the output is `null`.
How does Java do the trick in string concatenation?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Because Java converts the expression `"A String" + x` to something along the lines of `"A String" + String.valueOf(x)`

In actual fact I think it probably uses `StringBuilder`s, so that:

```
"A String " + x + " and another " + y
```

resolves to the more efficient

```
new StringBuilder("A String ")
    .append(x)
    .append(" and another ")
    .append(y).toString()
```

This uses the `append` methods on String builder (for each type), which handle `null` properly

Comment: IIRC, it doesn't actually hit up `String.valueOf(y)`.  There are overloads of `StringBuilder.append` for every possible type, and `append(Object)` handles the null directly.  You can replace the "I think it probably" with "it" though.

Comment: Yes - I'm old skool, I'm afraid - from back in the day when string concatenation was unperformant!

Comment: Just inspected the code for `append(Object)`, and it does in fact delegate to `String.valueOf()`.  *Inside* the method though.  So they boil down to the same calls.

Answer (score 9):

Java uses `StringBuilder.append( Object obj )` behind the scenes.

It is not hard to imagine its implementation.

```
public StringBuilder append( Object obj )
{
   if ( obj == null )
   {
       append( "null" );
   }
   else
   {
       append( obj.toString( ) );
   }

   return this;
}
```

Comment: Link to implementation: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/StringBuilder.java#170

Answer (score 4):

The code `"" + null` is converted by the compiler to

```
new StringBuffer().append("").append(null);
```

and StringBuffer replaces null with the string "null". So the result is the string "null".

Comment: Just a small correction; it's now StringBuilder not StringBuffer.  Thread safety isn't a concern with String concatenation (over the lifetime of the builder anyway).

Comment: Why would one want/need to write `"" + null` instead of just `"null"`?  Is that example just for academic exercise?

Comment: @user46874: i think it must have been an experiment to see how nulls get printed.