# why am i getting a NullPointerException Java

Tags: java

So im writing a Java programming, I have 2 classes, and a class test that uses these 2 classes. running eclipseIDE, it keeps telling me i have a NullPointerException at the `"s+=c.getName() + " " +... "`

this is a method in Student.

```
public String getCourses()
    {
        String s = "";
        for(Course c: this.courses)
        {
            s+=c.getName() + " " + c.getID() + " " + c.getScore(this.id);
            s+="\n";
        }
        return s;
    }
```

it calls this method that is in the Course class.

```
public String getID()
{
    return this.id;
}
```

i tried only doing getName(); it had no issue, however once i added getID() it became an issue. getName is the same type of code, it returns the "name" of the object as a string.

name and id is "initialized" via a constructor

```
Stacktrace:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at hw6.Student.getCourses(Student.java:47)
    at hw6.CourseStudent_test.main(CourseStudent_test.java:100)
```

this is the getScore method

```
public double getScore(String id)
    {
        int i = 0;
        for(; i < this.students.length;i++)
        {
            if(this.students[i].getID() == id )
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        return this.scores[i];
    }
```

Comment: Please post your stacktrace

Comment: added @ScaryWombat

Comment: Please attach your whole Course class content

Comment: @Derek.W is there a way to post them in some way? both class has over 100+ lines

Comment: `c.getScore(this.id);` looks dodgy.  Please post this code.  Also confirm the value of `this.id`

Comment: Or provide the link to show the whole codes.

Comment: @Derek.W , i just added a link to a github, of both codes

Comment: Your link does not work

Comment: No not a link to the code.  The code needs to be in the question.

Comment: like i said, both classes combined is a total of almost 300 lines of codes. @StephenC

Comment: (Even a working link is not good enough.  What is to stop you deleting the githup repo, for example.)

Comment: So the solution to that is to write a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: And we most likely do not need the entire code to spot the immediate cause of the NPE.

Comment: okay i posted the getScore method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue, Because of the "For each " loop, when it gets to an Null object, it tries to run the getter methods, however each time it returns null, as there is no "value" for each variable within that object, so i just added a if condition to check if the object is "null"

Answer (score 2):

If the exception is occurring where your stacktrace + question says it is, then one of the elements in `courses` must be `null`.

Reasoning:

- If the exception was thrown inside one of the `Course` method calls, then the stacktrace would show that method as the top stack frame.
- If one of those 3 calls returned `null`, you wouldn't get an NPE.  You would just get "null" in the resulting concatenation; see [String concatenation with Null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4199298/string-concatenation-with-null).

Comment: yes, all the get...() returns a String value,

Comment: That confirms my diagnosis.  Check what is in `courses`, and how a `null` has gotten into there.  That will be where the problem is.

Comment: The two first points are sufficient to conclude.

Comment: @StephenC how would i go about checking how a null gotten into the courses object array?

Comment: By looking at the code that initializes and assigns into the array!   I assume you are aware of the fact that the elements of the array will be default initialized to `null`.

Comment: Most bugs can be found by carefully reading your code and thinking / reasoning about what it does.

Comment: so, i did a little debugging using the println statement. it is printing out all 3 returned values with no issue, and non are null.

Comment: @Gary Are you now saying that there is **no** NPE?

Comment: It is not the returned values that it the problem.  It is the `null` values in the `this.courses` array.  If my diagnosis is >>incorrect<< then there is something else going on, and we actually really do need to see a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: no, it still giving my NPE, but neither of those 3 methods, returned a "null" @ScaryWombat

Comment: Well ... yea ... if you look for the broom in the fridge you won't find it :-)   I already explained why the NPE is not caused by those 3 methods returning `null`.  The broom won't fit in the fridge.  Try looking in the broom cupboard ...

Comment: @gary I suggest that maybe your initial diagnosis of where the NPE is happening is incorrect.

Comment: so there are null values within the this.courses array. I do have an Addcourses method, and i think thats the issue.

Comment: I have to leave this now.  Good luck.  The trick to solving this is to think logically ...